# Natives broken on Mac

Tags: java, macos, native, lwjgl

About a month ago I used a MacBook for doing my programming, and LWJGL could load the natives perfectly fine, no problems. Today I loaded up the same laptop again and the natives refuse to load with `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /Users/kenzietogami/Dropbox/<project name redacted>/./lib/natives/liblwjgl.dylib`. This also happens for Minecraft, so it's not isolated to my project. The project works fine for Windows as well.

What could be causing this native loading failure?

Comment: [Gatekeeper](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5290)?

Comment: Let me check, but that means it got enabled in that month of me not touching it; because I've not updated anything.

Comment: I don't think it is; as this isn't a new thing so it wouldn't have worked earlier if GateKeeper blocked it.